# Node not seeing module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, typescript

I have the following compiled typescript class in file: User.js

```
"use strict";
var mongo = require('mongoose');
var User = (function () {
    function User(data) {
        this.Name = data.name;
        this.City = data.city;
        this.State = data.state;
    }
    User.prototype.nameUpperCase = function () {
        return this.Name.toUpperCase();
    };
    return User;
}());
exports.User = User;
var schema = new mongo.Schema({
    Name: String,
    City: String,
    State: String
});
schema.method('nameUpperCase', User.prototype.nameUpperCase);
var Users = mongo.model('User', schema);
```

usertest.js contents:

```
require('User.js');  <-- no matter what I put here

var u1 = new Users({Name: 'Matthew Brown', City:'Austin',State:'TX'});
var u2 = new Users({Name: 'Jonathan Andrews', City:'Georgetown',State:'TX'});
var u3 = new Users({Name: 'Mom(Rose Brown)', City:'Holiday Island',State:'AR'});
var u4 = new Users({Name: 'Ditto(Bill Brown Jr.)', City:'Charlton',State:'MA'});

Users.create(u1,function(err, u1) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("User %s created",u1.Name);
    }
});
Users.create(u2,function(err, u2) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("User %s created",u2.Name);
    }

});
Users.create(u3,function(err, u3) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("User %s created",u3.Name);
    }
});
Users.create(u4,function(err, u4) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("User %s created",u4.Name);
    }
});
```

I have tried everything and i keep getting the error from node saying that it can not find the module 'User' or above, it will say it can not find 'User.js'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In User.js you are not exporting mongoose `User` Model

Change

```
var Users = mongo.model('User', schema);
```

to

```
exports.Users = mongo.model('User', schema);
```

Also in `usertest.js`, `Users` not defined anywhere

Change

```
require('User.js');
```

to

```
var Users = require('./User.js').Users; // check for relative path here
```

Now

> can not find 'User.js'

is because you are not setting relative path.

You can refer without relative path to `node_modules` folder libraries, inbuilt `node.js` libraries & Global libraries